# Sublime text plugin usage without Admin right

Tags: plugins, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I want to install sublime text 3 plugins at my workplace. I have asked my administrator to install some of the plugins but the plugin installation is local to the user. He installed plugins from his admin account which won't get reflected in the any other user account.
So what will be my alternatives to installing plugins to sublime other than the usual way ?

Comment: I use Windows and Linux and I do not understand what you wrote. If you have a user account on THE workstation, anything installed by the Admin regarding the two above is GOING be 'reflected' to all other users on THE workstation, and the workstation alone. I understand you need to use the plugins, but the installation is obviously up to an admin for the given workstation so... You need admin rights to the workstation, or sublime needs to be running with admin rights, there are no other obvious choices.

Comment: To resolve fast, use portable version. It's on the site.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps : https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/install-sublime-text3-without-sudo/42893
It allows using sublime text without the use of SUDO.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill I converted this from a link only answer to quoting the accepted answer the user was referencing in the linked post.  According to meta that us a preferred method of improving an otherwise relevant link only answer